# I need a sql query to match two strings in where clause

Tags: sql, string

'IP' is text field in both whiteList and BlackList tables(two different tables).'ip' is string storing ip address of current client.i want to check first if the ip address of client is in black list and then in whitelist(if not in blacklist).As it is string matching so '=' operator is not generating correct result.Also dont want to use 'like' because i am not searching for pattern rather exact match.

```
 string[] ipPort = txtCIP.Text.Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2);
            string ip = ipPort[0];
            con.Open();
            //MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
            string query = "SELECT count(*) from BlackList WHERE IP=ip";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            int rowCount =1;
            rowCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            string wlq = "SELECT count(*) from WhiteList WHERE IP=ip";
            SqlCommand cmd_wl = new SqlCommand(wlq, con);
            int rowcount_wl;
          rowcount_wl = (int)cmd_wl.ExecuteScalar();

          if (rowCount > 1)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("This IP is black Listed.Please retry after a few seconds.");
          }

          else if (rowcount_wl > 0)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("This ip is present in white list.");
          }
          else
          { MessageBox.Show("IP is not present in whitelist"); }
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Why is the = operator not generating the right result? Could you provide an example of something it is not selecting correctly?

Comment: What isn't working in your code? Your question doesn't make that clear.

Comment: This seems bad design.  You should use one table and have a one column which indicates if the ip is on the black or white list. IP column should also be unique (you don't want a ip in the black and white list table).  Also add the programming lang. This isn't clearly SQL only, c# ?

Comment: It is giving exception.'datatypes text and text are incompatible to the equal to operator.

Comment: i cant include both blacklist and whitelist ip's in same table becasue i also have some other things like roles of authenticated users in whitelist.Also scenario of deletion etc from blacklist and whitelist vary.yes it is SQL server database with c# windows app

Comment: @ayna, that doesn't sound like a good reason. Of course it could be, but its unlikely. Point is you can now easily end up with one ip in two table, that doesn't make sense. A IP is either black or whitelisted, not both. Did you follow 'database normalization codd' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) ?

Comment: @Rogier,i am getting your point..but demand of my scenario is that both lists should be two different tables as tasks i have to perform with data of both are pretty dissimilar like auto deletion in blacklist and roles discovery from whitelist..i am adding some dummy data in both tables and it is supposed to be taken from another system(i am expecting that the one who has designed database would have follow some rules e.g.check if an ip address is in blacklist then can not insert the very same ip in whitelist.so im not going through normalization.

Answer (score 2):

I think issue is in your select,varialbe [ip] should be outside double quotes,

```
 string query = "SELECT count(*) from BlackList WHERE IP=ip";
```

should be like this,

```
 string query = "SELECT count(*) from BlackList WHERE IP=" + ip;
```

AND

```
string wlq = "SELECT count(*) from WhiteList WHERE IP=ip";
```

should be like this,

```
string wlq = "SELECT count(*) from WhiteList WHERE IP=" + ip;
```

Comment: you have made a perfect catch!

Comment: @ayna, are you getting any error? please explain what is issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "SELECT count(*) from BlackList WHERE IP=" + ip;
string wlq = "SELECT count(*) from WhiteList WHERE IP=" + ip;
```

Your IP is stored in a variable, so use it as a variable. When you do WHERE IP=ip it's searching for the string = ip. So when you compare an IP 192.168.1.1 you are comparing against the word ip e.g.

```
if ("192.168.1.1" == "ip")
```

This will return false obviously.

Answer (score -1):

String concatenation needs to be done to pass value of variable using plus operator

```
string query = "SELECT count(*) from BlackList WHERE IP="+ip;
```

<strike>without it the WHERE clause is searching for word ip rather than value contained in variable ip</strike>

Executing your query

```
 string query = "SELECT count(*) from BlackList WHERE IP=ip";
```

<strike>will throw error ***invalid column name ip***</strike>

will return all rows as you are matching column IP with itself i.e ip

To be searched as a string literal in `WHERE` clause , **ip** would need to be enclosed in single qoutes but ofcourse you don't want this.